# Entity framework - Reducing round trips to the database

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm writing an app using WPF, Entity framework and SQLServer, all very run of the mill stuff. I was having a look at what calls get made to the database using sql profiler and found quite a few unnecessary calls. The first one was solved pretty easy but I have included it for anyone reading this thread in the future. Assuming I have a table structure with 3 tables like this Invoice->InvoiceDetail->Product

1) When I load up an Invoice object, it will then execute a seperate statement to retrieve each InvoiceDetail item. This is solved pretty easy by using the Include statement, eg

```
context.Invoices.Include("InvoiceDetails").Where(i => i.Something == somethingelse);
```

2) When I delete an Invoice the database has a cascade delete which automatically deletes all of the InvoiceDetails. However EF still insists on calling a delete for each of the InvoiceDetail objects that it has in memory. If an invoice has 100 items on it then it will execute 101 statements instead of 1. This is bad.

3) In addition to the extra statements executed in point 2, assuming each InvoiceDetail object points to a product and I have caused the products to loaded into memory (this would happen if I showed the invoice before I deleted it) then EF executes a useless update statement on every product!!!! In fact this update statement is more than useless because if someone else has changed something about the product in the mean time then this code will change the data back!! If I'm logging changes then we get useless log entries. I suspect it is doing this because Product would have had an InvoiceDetails collection which has had some items removed, but the Product itself has not changed so why the update?

Thanks for reading
Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Wow I don't use EF and now I am not sure I want to.  On just simple properties with binding to the property I notice multiple calls.  For any property that has and expensive call to SQL I store the last request and answer and if the new request is the same I return the last answer.

Comment: In response to "On just simple properties with binding to the property I notice multiple calls", this is probably covered in my point 1 above. This part of EF actually works quite well. Although I do get the feeling that EF is not really there yet and will feel more complete at some point in the future. It's missing some really basic functionality such as undo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The initial behavior was something known as lazy loading. You have replaced it with eager loading which is exact solution for this problem.
2. For entity framework this is the only correct behavior because EF doesn't support any batch modifications. Every record must be deleted with its own statement and round trip to the database. Once you load entities to memory you simply have to delete them one by one otherwise you will get exception before any database call will be done (= database cascade delete will not help you). The only workaround is custom stored procedure for deletion and disposing the current context after running the stored procedure because its internal state will not be consistent with the database.
3. This is interesting. It would require little bit more investigation but it can be simply design flaw / bug in EF and you will most probably not avoid it (unless you use stored procedure as described in 2.). If you want to avoid overwriting changes in `Product` you must involve [optimistic concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738618.aspx). In such case your changes will not be overwritten but your delete will fail with `OptimisticConcurrencyException`. I will check this behavior later and let you know if I'm able to reproduce it and find any workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "The only workaround is custom stored procedure for deletion" this is something I had considered and I have done this in a few places. It seems a little messy to me because you have to track down every place that stores data and set it again. With regards to no 3 and using some sort of multu-user checking, making the delete fail for no good reason would be bad. Interesting that calling the stored proc and recreating the context solves both problems. It seems this solution could be the best answer, it's something I have used when SaveChanges fails.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this as a solution to let SQL Server handle the cascading deletes without the EF hit.

```
  Public Sub DeleteCheckedOutByUser(ByVal username As String)
    Dim cmd As String = String.Format("delete  Maintenance.CheckoutManager where CheckOutTo = '{0}'", username)
    _context.ExecuteStoreCommand(cmd)
  End Sub
```

Sorry it's in VB, that's what my current client is using. If you have any trouble translating what I'm saying just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you do with the entity objects that are in memory? Do you detach them or mark them deleted some how? Or just create a new context?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the cascading deletes (and presumably rely on SQL Server to do the deletes), see the approach here: http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/12/17/ef4-cpt5-code-first-remove-cascading-deletes.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't quite get what they are doing there. Can't I just turn the cascade property off anyway?

Comment: What you want to do (I assume) is to remove the cascading deletes that EF implements (the 100+ extra calls), and rely on the ones implemented in SQL Server.  Here is a declarative example of how to set the OnDelete element's Action, which amounts to the same thing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx

Comment: Ideally I want the entity framework to cascade delete all the in memory objects but not call the delete on the database. I stumbled on that "Tip 33" page earlier today but as far as I know it just explains the problem with no mention of a solution or even that a solution is required. :-)